# C++ multithreading

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Есть приложение сетевое, в нем открыто 2 сокета, есть метод который читает эти данные и после добавляет в очередь, в очереди используются блокировки так вот, падает(не часто) но падает

вот последний трейс:

```
#0  0x00002aaaadae6507 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:55
#1  0x00002aaaadae78da in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00002aaaadadf59d in __assert_fail_base (fmt=0x2aaaadc1c6b8 "%s%s%s:%u: %s%sAssertion `%s' failed.\n%n", assertion=assertion@entry=0x2aaaac45e8b5 "(-(e)) != 3 || !robust", file=file@entry=0x2aaaac45e898 "../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c", line=line@entry=355, function=function@entry=0x2aaaac45e9b0 <__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.8680> "__pthread_mutex_lock_full") at assert.c:92
#3  0x00002aaaadadf652 in __GI___assert_fail (assertion=assertion@entry=0x2aaaac45e8b5 "(-(e)) != 3 || !robust", file=file@entry=0x2aaaac45e898 "../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c", line=line@entry=355, function=function@entry=0x2aaaac45e9b0 <__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.8680> "__pthread_mutex_lock_full") at assert.c:101
#4  0x00002aaaac4556dd in __pthread_mutex_lock_full (mutex=0x2aab13c58ac8) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:355
#5  0x0000000001ce1fe5 in __gthread_mutex_lock (__mutex=0x2aab13c58ac8) at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5.3.1/bits/gthr-default.h:748
#6  0x0000000001ce2c45 in std::mutex::lock (this=0x2aab13c58ac8) at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/mutex:135
```

при входе в метод чтения пакета создается лок

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> sessionGuard(_sessionLock, std::defer_lock);
```

далее идет свитч на некоторые типы пакетов, всё остальное попадает в очередь таким образом:

```
вход в блок
sessionGuard.lock();
session->AddPacket(new Packet(std::move(packet)));
выход из блока
```

Метод на добавление в очередь:

```
void add(const T& item)
{
    _lock.lock(); <- вот тут при попытке блокировать падает 
    _queue.push_back(item);
    _lock.unlock();
}
```

Как я понимаю по трейсу идет попытка сделать блокировку уже заблокированный мьютекс?

debian 8, clang 3.6

Comment: Уточните, что значит "вот тут при попытке блокировать падает". Дело в том, что при блокировке уже блокированного мьютекса не должно ничего падать. Скорее, программа ловит deadlock  и "виснет".

Comment: Ну вот тогда не понятно почему так происходит. Есть мысль такая: что если сессия извне закрывается во время того как идет добавление пакета в очередь?

Comment: Ну так в таком случае нужен не Ваш трейс, а код (фрагмент кода). Судя по симптомам, Вы не лочите область, с которой работаете. Т.е. пытаетесь получить доступ (читаете либо пишите) к объекту, который изменяется в данный момент (либо его еще не существует, либо его уже не существует).

Comment: Чтение пакета и добавление в очередь: http://pastebin.com/REpYKk9C
Очередь: http://pastebin.com/L6sFKnw7
Вот такая штука отрубает отрубает сокеты: http://pastebin.com/NzvvXnEw

Answer (score 1):

Перво-наперво: `std::unique_lock` не обязан быть thread safe и его нельзя использовать между потоками, `std::mutex` — можно, `std::unique_lock` — нельзя.
По уму, Ваш код пишется так:

```
std::mutex _sessionLock;
```

Потом

```
вход в блок
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> sessionGuard{_sessionLock};
session->AddPacket(new Packet(std::move(packet)));
выход из блока
```

И:

```
void add(const T& item)
{
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{_lock};
    _queue.push_back(item);
}
```

Проблема также может быть в попытке рекурсивного захвата мьютекса — проверьте, что этого не происходит. Т.к. рекурсивный захват это UB, то может быть в том числе и падение. На самом деле, я уже встречал подобный вопрос на enSO, тогда было падение у gcc с рекурсивным захватом.

Почему UB? Потому, что у `lock` есть следующие требования:
*[thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]p7*:

> Requires: If m is of type std::mutex, std::timed_mutex, or
>   std::shared_timed_mutex, the callingthread **does not own the mutex**.

А *[res.on.required]* говорит нам:

> Violation of the preconditions specified in a function’s Requires:
>   paragraph results in **undefined behavior** unless the function’s Throws:
>   paragraph specifies throwing an exception when the precondition is
>   violated.

---

Рекурсивный `lock` можно довольно просто отловить:

```
void add(const T& item)
{
    thread_local int counter = 0;
    counter++;
    if(counter > 1)
        std::cout << "Achtung!\n";
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{_lock};
    _queue.push_back(item);
    counter--;
}
```

Comment: У топикастера программа "падает". А при рекурсивном захвате такого не будет. Да и рекурсивным захват можно называть условно. На деле раза два-три он захватится - не больше. Кстати, можно еще просто-напросто перед каждым локом выводить в консоль количество локов. Если оно будет больше нуля - ищи проблему.

Comment: @MaxZS, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, lock_guard сразу захватит сессию, а стоит defer_lock в unique_lock, helgrind детектит такие проблемы?

Comment: @orion_gm, Я вставил `lock_guard` ровно в тех местах, где Вы сами лочите Ваш `unique_lock`, поэтому разницы тут нет. А вот использовать его меж потоков всё равно нельзя, никак. Что касается helgrind — понятия не имею. Сейчас обновлю вопрос с простой техникой, как найти эту проблему

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Вот такое появляется http://pastebin.com/DfuUMkKD
И сокет паходу уходит в дедлок

Comment: @orion_gm, что это? Отлаживать и выявлять проблему, Вам всё равно придётся самому, отладка через фору невозможна. Попробовали найти рекурсию?

Comment: это последний бэктрейс, ваш код не получается собрать для поиска рекурсии, при линке ругается на thread_local

Comment: @orion_gm, не должно быть никаких ошибок, clang умеет `thread_local`. К сожалению, больше я Вам ничем помочь не могу.

Comment: если можете напишите, пожалуйста в скайп orion.gm

Comment: @orion_gm, без обид, но я помогаю только в рамках форума. У меня нет продолжительного времени, которое я мог бы уделить отладке чужого кода, тем более удалённо. Ответ у Вас уже есть, Вам осталось найти почему у Вас получается рекурсивный вызов — это нужно делать самостоятельно, на своей машине.

Comment: Да просто пару вопрос задать :). ну ладно, спрошу тут.
Сейчас вылетел дамп, где чётко видно что к очереди имеет доступ 2 потока, но это еще без замены на lock_guard